# how to create separate files for validations in ionic2?

Tags: angular, validation, ionic2

I'm trying to separate the validation methods to a single file in ionic2/angular2 i.e create a reusable code for validation that i can use in future for other project also

1. I would like to know what is the best way to create a reusable file in angular2 or ionic2.
2. The second problem is i have tried creating a separate **validation.ts** file and calling that method but it's giving a weird error.

I tried 2 ways.First create a file **username.ts** and create a method inside it.
In the second i created a provider and placed the same method inside it.

Code:Username.ts

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class UsernameValidator {

constructor() {

}


  validateEmail(email) {
    var re = new RegExp(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i);
    return re.test(email);
  }

  validatePhone(phone) {
      var re = /^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
      return re.test(phone);
  }

  checkUsername(control){

    if(this.validateEmail(control.value)||this.validatePhone(control.value))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }



}
```

Same way a provider also

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the Validation provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Validation {

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello Validation Provider');
  }

  validateEmail(email) {
    return true;
  }

  validatePhone(phone) {
      return true;
  }

  checkUsername(control){
    console.log(control.value)
    var checkemail=this.validateEmail(control.value);
    var checkphone=this.validatePhone(control.value);
    if(checkemail||checkphone)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

}
```

calling the function from the login.ts file

```
 this.loginForm=formBuilder.group({
        username: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required]),validation.checkUsername],
        password: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
```

evrytime i'm getting the error as

> : Cannot read property 'validateEmail' of undefined

My understanding of angular and ionic is not enough to get past this error.
Please help

Thanks!

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yes that error was removed.but what about my first question.What is the best way to create reusable code.?

Comment: A singleton provider works.. you can use it throughout your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the function here:

```
    username: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required]),validation.checkUsername],
```

`validation.checkUsername` takes the scope of the calling function and not the scope of `Validation` class as you need here.So `this` does not refer to `Validation`.

You can resolve this either by defining the function as an arrow function:

```
checkUsername:any = (control) => {
    console.log(control.value)
    var checkemail=this.validateEmail(control.value);
    var checkphone=this.validatePhone(control.value);
    if(checkemail||checkphone)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
```

**OR** in your Validation constructor, bind the function to `this` like so:

```
 constructor() {
    console.log('Hello Validation Provider');
    this.checkUsername = this.checkUsername.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
checkUsername(control){
   if(this.validateEmail(control.value)||this.validatePhone(control.value))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
```

`control` is undefined, and you're trying to get a property `value` of undefined. You should wrap checkUsername in an `if` statement, like this:

```
checkUsername(control){
    if(control && control.value) { 
if(this.validateEmail(control.value)||this.validatePhone(control.value))
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
          return false;
      }
}
```

Or in your provider,

```
  checkUsername(control){
    if (control && control.value) {
    console.log(control.value)
    var checkemail=this.validateEmail(control.value);
    var checkphone=this.validatePhone(control.value);
    if(checkemail||checkphone)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
    }
  }
```

That way, you will always get a value.

Comment: OP is talking about a different error.. `control` doesnt seem to be throwing it

Comment: I logged control.value and it was not undefined.